# Changing Assembly Name Breaks My XAML Designer

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010

When I change my assembly name in VS2010 project properties, all my views stop working in the designer and state none of my clr-namespace's can be found.  Rebuilding the solution does not fix this yet I can build, run and install the solution with the assembly name changed.
Is their another step I have to take to fix this?

Comment: Did you also update the default namespace for your assembly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested in comments

- Ensure default namespace is set correctly in project properties

And

- Ensure all Xaml files have the updated assembly-name in the clr-namespace
- Close visual studio, go through the entire project structure, deleting bin, obj directories, *.suo, *.user files,
- Reopen visual studio and rebuild

Comment: I haven't got the assembly name in the clr-namespace as it is part of the same assembly. Namespace hasn't changed either.

Comment: Did you try the clear out all bin/obj directories, suo, user files and restart studio?

Comment: Yep, the good old delete everything and start again trick :) Glad to be of help!

Comment: Good advice. I'd already tried closing and reopening, but deleting the bin and obj directories did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: I know this is old, but it is worth mentioning that source paths (e.g. for Resource Dictionaries) sometimes utilizes the assembly name and hence must also be updated.